# How to resolve error when launching OSeo4W Shell: Windows cannot find .bat file?

Tags: ogr2ogr, batch, osgeo4w, shell

I downloaded and installed OSGeo4W to use ogr2ogr, but the the program OSGeo4W will not run. On launching the shell, I receive an error stating the .bat file cannot be found in specified directory (image included) even though the .bat file is in the specified directory.

When I run OSGeo4W as an administrator the shell will open with the error of filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect (image included).

I have uninstalled and reinstalled OSGeo4W in an attempt to resolve the error; however, I don't think it is an installation issue since I was using it yesterday without producing the described error.

The only thing that I've done since yesterday that could have effected OSGeo4W is install Cygwin on my computer, which runs Windows, to use batch.

[image: When launching OSGeo4W Shell I receive this error.]

[image: Running OSGeo4W as an administrator will open the shell with the error of filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin might have altered your system PATH variable. You might have to re-install OSGEO4W afterwards.

Alternatively, you can use the Gisinternal builds of GDAL, or the shell provided by the QGIS standalone installer. Or install to a different folder.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I reinstalled OSGeo4W after installing Cygwin   , which didn't work. How would I check the system path variable (Control Panel > View Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Edit Path)? If so, I do not believe it was changed but am uncertain.

I am not very familiar with GIS, so I don't know how to use the Gisinternal builds of GDAL. I will try the Shell provided by QGIS, and if that does not work, installing to a different folder.

Comment: From gisinternals, download http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1800-x64-gdal-1-11-3-mapserver-6-4-2.zip, extract it to a folder, and start SDKShell.bat. Much easier than OSGeo4W.